# Is there on-disk cache available on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, caching, uiwebview, nsurlcache

I found a project to improve the cache strategy on iPhone. Cos they are sure:
"[On iPhone OS, Apple did remove on-disk cache support for unknown reason](https://github.com/rs/SDURLCache)"

But, I do not think so, see deitail:
https://github.com/rs/SDURLCache/issues/39

I found there are two db files on folder"Library/Catches/com.company.appname/" with UIWebView app:

ApplicationCache.db, Cache.db

### and try those sqls

"select * from CacheResourceData", after opening ApplicationCache.db

"select * from cfurl_cache_receiver_data" on Cache.db

Both are cache file content on the disk

So now I am confused, Who can tell me the truth and the evidence?

Comment: if u access that database your application might get rejected

Comment: NSCache always saves in memory. NSURLCache has a different storage policy.

Comment: @phix23, I try to set a big Capacity with
    [NSURLCache setDiskCapacity:1024*1024*50]; so will it cause some problems, or affect the cache performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of iOS 5.0 `NSURLCache` uses on-disk cache: http://petersteinberger.com/blog/2012/nsurlcache-uses-a-disk-cache-as-of-ios5/

Answer (score 1):

**ApplicationCache.db** is used to cache HTML5 cache, and  **Cache.db** is used with NSURLCache.

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
```

sets **Cache.db**  empty. (Browse and see from Finder while using iOS simulator)

If you delete ApplicationCache.db from your directory  HTML5 cache gets lost.